# Can't display keyboard in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an UIWebView in an UIView, when I select my inputs in my webview the keyboard doesn't appear!

I don't know why!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in iOS6 now you can do this with "**keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction**":

keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction
A Boolean value indicating whether web content can programmatically display the keyboard.

@property (nonatomic) BOOL keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction
Discussion
When this property is set to YES, the user must explicitly tap the elements in the web view to display the keyboard (or other relevant input view) for that element. When set to NO, a focus event on an element causes the input view to be displayed and associated with that element automatically.

The default value for this property is YES.

Availability
Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
Declared In
UIWebView.h

reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html